# L'approche écosystémique du rétablissement et la relation entre plusieurs espèces : apports ?

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot, adjectifs, terminologie, synonymes

Dans un [article](https://www.lapresse.ca/environnement/especes-menacees/201811/17/01-5204611-la-protection-de-la-faune-canadienne-decriee-par-des-experts.php)<sup>1</sup> (*La Presse*) on trouve une référence à l'idée d'une :

> **Approche [écosystémique](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8366322)** du [rétablissement](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26529726), où on ne se penche pas sur
>   une seule espèce, mais sur la relation entre plusieurs espèces.

---

Au *Grand dictionnaire terminologique* on nous dit qu'*écosystémique* est l'adjectif pour « relatif à une unité écologique constituée d'un milieu naturel et de l'ensemble des organismes qui y vivent », relatif à l'*écosystème* quoi, alors que le *rétablissement* est un terme pour le « processus au cours duquel le déclin d'une espèce, d'une variété ou d'une population est jugulé et renversé jusqu'à ce que sa survie à l'état sauvage soit assurée ».

Sur [*Wiktionnaire*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/approche_syst%C3%A9mique) je trouve une acception d'[*approche*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/approche) [systémique](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/syst%C3%A9mique) appliquée au domaine et comprenant un exemple contenant le terme *écosystémique* qualifiant cette fois le mot *environnement* :

> [...]
>   3. (*Environnement*) Étude de la dynamique environnementale d’un système écologique.
>
> - *L’approche systémique semble être la démarche méthodologique adaptée    à l’appréciation des rapports entre la faune aviaire et son
>     environnement écosystémique martiniquais.* — (Jean-Raphaël Gros-Désormeaux, *L’Avifaune et son environnement : l’exemple du
>
>     système insulaire tropical martiniquais*, Publibook, 2004, page 13)

Enfin on aussi l'adjectif [*systématique*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/syst%C3%A9matique) dans le sens de *conforme à un système, méthodique* etc. (*TLFi*).

---

- Dans le texte de l'article, en locution nominale avec le déterminatif
  *du rétablissement* qui vise une espèce, si l'on oublie un instant la précision apportée par le complément qui suit (*où on*...), les
  adjectifs *écosystémique*, *systémique* et *systématique*
  réaliseraient-ils un apport équivalent avec l'*approche* ; au final
  est-ce le rétablissement, vu sa fonction, qui bénéficie de l'apport
  de l'adjectif (*rétablissement écosystémique* est-il cohérent) ?
- Par opposition à quel autre genre d'environnement ou comment devrait-on
  comprendre *environnement écosystémique* dans l'exemple du Wiktionnaire ?
- Y a-t-il un adjectif qui traduise plus directement qu'*écosystémique* ne le ferait l'apport de « la relation entre plusieurs espèces » introduite par le complément dans l'article (...*où on ne se penche pas sur une seule espèce, mais sur la relation entre plusieurs espèces*, ayant essentiellement valeur de relative) ?

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> ...qui dresse par ailleurs un constat révoltant de l'état lamentable dans lequel se trouvent les espèces animales sur la planète et, comble d'immondice, où on peut lire qu'« au [Canada](http://assets.wwf.ca/downloads/LPRC_ES_French_web.pdf) seulement, les populations de mammifères ont chuté de 43 % ; les populations d'amphibiens et de reptiles, de 34 % ; les populations de poissons, de 20 % ; et certains types d'oiseaux ont perdu entre 43 et 69 % de leurs populations » depuis 1970.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Les adjectifs "écosystémique" et "systémique" se rapportent à des relations complexes, mais "systématique" est beaucoup plus large car il englobe toute la diversité de ces relations à toutes les échelles et dans toute leur complexité. L'approche écosystémique permet quant à elle de se fixer une échelle (un écosystème donné) et donc de se focaliser sur une partie seulement de la complexité du problème (ce qui est déjà énorme).

J'éviterais par contre l'utilisation du terme "systématique" dans ce contexte  puisqu'il porterait à confusion 1) avec une approche selon des règles préconçues, procédant souvent étape par étape, ce qui est d'ailleurs à l'origine de la systématique (en sciences naturelles), qui est la science de la classification des taxons, ou 2) avec une notion de constance, comme pour  une erreur systématique (en statistique, se dit d'un événement qui se reproduit toujours de la même façon, ce qui induit une moyenne biaisée).

Pour résumer, dans le cas d'approches "systémique" ou "écosystémique", on essaie de comprendre un système complexe, alors que dans le cas d'une approche "systématique" on applique un système connu.

Comment: *«Systématique»* en science peut aussi qualifier quelque chose qui ne varie pas, qui est constant *(erreur systématique, par exemple)*, avec parfois une nuance d’exhaustif *(par exemple, on pourrait dire d’une étude ou d’un raisonnement qui analyse tous les cas possibles qu’ils utilisent une méthode systématique)*. Une autre raison selon moi d’éviter le terme en la circonstance décrite par la question, puisque l’on tente d’agir sur un système en place pour l’aider, non de créer un système pour réparer les écosystèmes.

Comment: Il y a effectivement plusieurs raison d'exclure ce terme dans ce cas. Merci, j'ai mis ma réponse à jour

Answer (score 1):

**A**

1. Il faut dire que ce que j'entrevois dans cette question d'équivalence de termes présuppose que l'idée de système, conçue généralement, est préservée lorsque restreinte à l'écologie : on passe seulement d'un ensemble de relations quelconques à un ensemble spécifique dont les particularités restent au niveau de l'écologie; le mot « système » ne prend pas une nouvelle dimension indépendante de ce qui est écologique dans ce système particulier dit « écosystème ». Il me semble évident alors que, le mot « écosystème » définissant une particularisation de l'idée de système au domaine de l'écologie, on laisse à la traine une précision capitale chaque fois que l'on réfère au système plutôt qu'à l'écosystème; cependant, ce raccourcissement du terme, une fois qu'il n'y a plus de doute quant au type de système qui nous occupe semble aussi une possibilité au moyen de laquelle continuer à parler d'écosystème; il n'y aurait en cela qu'un cas de plus d'une pratique très courante du discours; évidemment, dans une discussion où d'autres types de système ont une importance, ce n'est plus la même chose. Cette utilisation possible de « système » tend à être confirmé par la définition de « systémique » dans le TLFi, plus précisément par l'exemple qui est fourni pour cette définition;

   > a) Qui concerne un système ou qui agit sur un système. **Approche systémique** d'une question. Le côté parcellaire de son enseignement actuel [de la biologie], qui insiste trop sur l'aspect analytique et pas assez sur **les « relations systémiques »** au sein des organismes vivants et entre eux-mêmes et leur environnement (Le Sauvage, janv. 1976, p. 53, col. 1).
2. La seconde équivalence est hors de question sur la base de l'acception de « systémique » qui s'impose et de la simple définition de l'adjectif « systématique » ;

   > a) [Corresp. à système A 1; en parlant des connaissances, des démarches, des travaux scientifiques] Qui est conforme à un système (de connaissance, d'analyse, d'étude, de raisonnement). Synon. méthodique.
3. Dit-on la même chose en utilisant les termes « approche écosystémique au rétablissement » et « rétablissement écosystémique » ?
   Du point de vue de la syntaxe, non, il ne s'agit pas de la même signification.
   Est-ce que oui ou non une signification peut être attachée à ce terme ?
   « Approche systémique » dans le TLFi est considéré comme étant un des syntagmes du dictionnaire (syntagmes en italique); on peut donc conclure que « approche écosystémique » l'est aussi, il suffit de particulariser la définition. Lorsque l'on trouve un syntagme dans le dictionnaire il s'agit d'un syntagme reconnu et défini au point même où porté dans le dictionnaire (définition en caractères normaux). Le fait que « rétablissement écosystémique » ne soit pas parmi les syntagmes laisse supposer trois choses, soit sa définition n'a pas été faite dans la littérature du sujet, soit elle n'a pas été relevée (possiblement rejetée) par les lexicographes, soit le concept est très récent et il n'y a eu encore l'opportunité de le faire figurer. *Il n'y a pas dans le domaine de la formation des syntagmes de critère très étroit sur le plan de la cohérence*; on fait dire à une combinaison pratiquement ce que l'on veut dans certaines limites. C'est cet état de chose qui rend nécessaire plusieurs sources dans la littérature du sujet pour permettre de vérifier qu'une définition (ou plus) existe. Il me semble donc qu'il n'est pas question de parler de la cohérence, si ce n'est qu'au niveau le plus élémentaire; si le terme n'est pas défini dans le livre où on le trouve, c'est qu'il est très courant et défini dans des ouvrages de fondation.

**B**

1. Dans un [écosystème](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89cosyst%C3%A8me) l'environnement écosystémique ou biotope, qui est aussi appelé *l'environnement de l'écosystème*, consiste du milieu non vivant dans lequel se trouvent les êtres vivants du système. Lorsque l'on parle de l'environnement écosystémique de la faune aviaire, cela réfère très certainement à la partie de la matière non vivante qui constitue l'environnement de la faune aviaire à l'exclusion de son environnement vivant.

**C**

1. Je ne peux pas trouver de trace d'un tel adjectif.